# EPiServer 7 & Mvc - Local Block with Controller (and tag) - doesn't auto refresh in On Page Editing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, episerver, episerver-7

I am using EPiServer 7.5+ and have a scenario where *some* of my [Local Blocks](http://joelabrahamsson.com/working-programmatically-with-local-blocks-in-episerver-7/) are not updating after being edited in the On Page Editing window.

I either have to do a full page refresh after editing the impacted Local Block, or use the [FullRefreshPropertiesMetaData](http://world.episerver.com/Documentation/Items/Developers-Guide/EPiServer-CMS/7/Content/Pages-and-Blocks/How-To/Edit-hints-in-MVC/#FullRefreshPropertiesMetaData), which just refreshes the whole page anyway.

**Why are some Local Blocks not refreshing correctly?**

After investigating a bit I have noticed that this issue only impacts Local Blocks that have their own Controller.

**Example Code**

Pages / Blocks:

```
[ContentType("nguid")]
public class SimpleLocalBlock : BlockData{
    public virtual string Text {get;set;}
}

[ContentType("nguid")]
public class AdvancedLocalBlock : BlockData{
    public virtual string Text {get;set;}
} 

[ContentType("nguid")]
public class MyPage : PageData
{
   public virtual SimpleLocalBlock Simple {get;set;}
   public virtual AdvancedLocalBlock Advanced {get;set;}
}
```

Controller:

```
public class AdvancedLocalBlockController : BlockController<AdvancedLocalBlock>
{
    public override ActionResult Index(MultiLinksBlock currentContent)
    {
        return PartialView(ViewPath, currentContent);
    }

    //Use ViewData["Tag"] to decide which View to use
    public virtual string ViewPath
    {
        get
        {
            var tag =
                this.ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.ViewData["Tag"]
                        as AdvancedViews?;

            if (tag.HasValue)
            {
                switch (tag)
                {
                    case AdvancedViews.View1:
                        return "~/Views/Shared/Blocks/View1.cshtml";

                    case AdvancedViews.View1:
                        return "~/Views/Shared/Blocks/View2.cshtml";
                 }
            }

            throw new Exception("Invalid Tag.");
        }
    }
```

Enum for controlling which View is used:

```
public Enum AdvancedViews
{
    View1 = 1,
    View2 = 2
}
```

View (Razor) - MyPage

```
@model MyPage 

@Html.PropertyFor(x => x.Simple)

@Html.PropertyFox(x => x.Advanced, new {Tag = AdvancedViews.View1})
```

View (Razor) - SimpleLocalBlock

```
@model SimpleLocalBlock

@Html.PropertyFor(x => x.Text)
```

View (Razor) - View1

```
@model AdvancedLocalBlock

@Html.PropertyFor(x => x.Text)
```

**Summary**

I can use On Page Editing when editing `Simple` and the block will refresh correctly inline on the page (ie doesn't need to refresh entire page).  But when I use On Page Editing with 'Advanced' I don't see the updates until I refresh the entire page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to inspect what EPiServer was doing after an On Page Edit, I realized `AdvancedLocalBlockController` was throwing an exception because EPi wasn't returning the ViewData correctly.

My View Dictionary key `Tag` was lower cased to `tag` and the Enum value (int) was passed instead of an instance of the Enum.

I ended up creating a helper to support EPi:

```
    public static T? ParseEnum<T>(this ViewDataDictionary d, string key)
        where T : struct
    {
        var dictObject = d[key];

        if (null == dictObject)
            return null;


        if (dictObject is T?)
            return dictObject as T?;

        T parsedEnum;
        if (Enum.TryParse(dictObject.ToString(), out parsedEnum))
            return parsedEnum;

        return null;
    }
```

and then updated my Controller:

```
var tag =
     this.ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.ViewData
         .ParseEnum<AdvancedViews>("tag");
```

After that my `AdvancedLocalBlock` behaved correctly in EPi On Page Editing